# Producing java classes from xsd file - JAXB

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaxb

I'm trying to learn to produce webservices with Java. I have added JAXB plugin to eclipse/plugin folder and I restarted eclipse. I have added a .xsd file to the source folder under eclipse and I am trying to generate classes from the xsd file. The tutorial mentions that, when I right click on the .xsd file, I should see an option called "JAXB 2.1 - > run XJC", but I don't see any such option on my eclipse installation. I only see "Generate - > JAXB Classes option". If I select this option and force it build classes, it gives out an error saying:

```
The classpath for this project does not appear to contain the necessary libraries to proceed with class generation.
Please insure that a JAXB implementation is available on the classpath. Couldn't find the main class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJFacade.
```

Can someone help me to figure out why am I not seeing that option under eclipse? I tried both galileo and Helios.

Comment: What's that got to do with invoking outlook from Java?

Comment: yikes.. im sorry, i was going to ask some entirely diff question yesterday.. I started on it but found the asnwer myself.. didn't notice that I had that title still on

Answer (score 12):

Check with the installed JRE in eclipse

Preference > Java > Installed JRE

If it points to jre then point it to jdk installation directory. It fixed the error for me

Answer (score 5):

Go to Window-> Preference -> Installed JREs

If You are pointing to JRE point to JDK issue will be resolved

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Eclipse Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) project (part of the [Eclipse Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) Project) has introduced new JAXB tooling that is available in the [Indigo release](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/) of Eclipse:

- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/jpa.php

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necromance this post!

On linux distros this may be a result of using `openjdk-*` packages rather than the oracle ones.
Offical oracle java can be installed following this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)

Any time I see `sun` mentioned in the exception it usually comes back to `open-jdk` vs `oracle-jdk`